# Reactjs Preload Embedded Content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a one page website using ReactJs. Different parts of the website are created as react components and are conditionally rendered based on which tabs the user selects in a navigation bar.

I am including embedded content in the form of a react youtube player and some embedded bandcamp players. Right now these reload whenever I render their parent component.

What is the best way to load this content once when the site is opened, and simply make it visible when necessary?

Comment: Are these embedded components getting unmounted from the DOM? Can you verify this by debugging `componentWillUnmount()` on those components?

Answer (score 0):

leave the components always in the page but with:

```
style={{ display: this.state.isTab1Selected ? 'block' : 'none' }}
```

so they will be there in the DOM but hidden (I think you mean that...)

Comment: That didn't work. I think it is because the components I am rendering are actually classes being conditionally rendered by a parent like so: `class Content extends Component {
  render() {
   console.log(this.props.nav);
   console.log(this.props.nav === "Designs");
   if(this.props.nav === "Designs"){
    return(
     <Designs style={{diplay: this.props.nav === "Designs" ? 'block' : 'none'}}/>
    );
   }
   if(this.props.nav === "Music"){
    return(
     <Music/>
    );
   }... etc ...`

Comment: `<Designs style={{diplay: this.props.nav === "Designs" ? 'block' : 'none'}}/>` Doesn't work because the Designs class contains a bunch of child components that aren't being affected by this style attribute changing.

Comment: you need to render all possible tabs always, but with the display thing. so <Designs <Music are always there. you can use the componentShouldUpdate() method and return false when is not needed to refresh, so <Designs will not refresh if it is not needed

Comment: well.. you need to design each component to don't remove the player never... through all the child of components

Comment: *don't remove from the DOM